# In NuxtJS How to configure different paths for publicPath, outputDir, and indexPath

Tags: vue.js, deployment, configuration, nuxt.js, production

I have situation when i deploy NuxtJS App for production that I need put files in different paths.

I used this configurations before in Vue App in vue.config.js and it’s works fine:

```
module.exports = {
    publicPath:'/assets/my_app/my_page/',
    outputDir: path.resolve('../my_app/public/my_page'),
    indexPath: path.resolve('../my_app/www/my_page.html'),
    devServer: {
        allowedHosts: ["my_site.com"],
        proxy: {
            '^/api': serverProxy,
            '^/assets': serverProxy,
            '^/files': serverProxy
        }
    }
};
```

How can do the same configurations in NuxtJS?

I tried this in nuxt.config.js but it not working:

```
build: {
    publicPath:'/assets/my_app/my_page/',
    // outputDir: path.resolve('../my_app/public/my_page'), 
  },
generate: {
    dir: path.resolve('../my_app/www/my_page.html'),
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

there are different Dir properties that you can use in nuxt.config. I think
[buildDir](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/configuration-glossary/configuration-builddir) ,[rootDir](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/configuration-glossary/configuration-rootdir) or [srcDir](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/configuration-glossary/configuration-srcdir)  can help you. However, you can access vue configuration and use your old solution by :
[nuxt.config vue.config property](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/configuration-glossary/configuration-vue-config)

Comment: Unfortunately, NuxtJS did not see publicPath, outputDir and indexPath  when I use them in vue.config property, probably because they belong to Vue CLI